# What is the proper way to use OmniAuth + Devise when developing a Facebook tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, devise, omniauth

I'm developing a simple Facebook app that will live in a Page's tab. I'm trying to figure out what the best method is for authenticating users. It seems that normal page redirection isn't right, which is how OmniAuth + Devise do it out of the box. How can I make this work with the JavaScript SDK's auth dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DMCS said, `FB.getLoginStatus` and `FB.login` will do it on the JS side of things. As for hooking it up with devise/omniauth, assuming you're using the latest omniauth where provider-specific logic has been split out into their own gems, the facebook-omniauth Github page explains it as so:

> The client-side flow supports parsing the authorization code from the signed request which Facebook puts into a cookie. This means you can to use the Facebook Javascript SDK as you would normally, and you just hit the callback endpoint (/auth/facebook/callback by default) once the user has authenticated in the FB.login success callback.

Now thats nice and easy. After the FB.login, a simple window.location.href = '/auth/facebook/callback' will do the trick!

Comment: If you run into unknown errors you might want to use define a `failure` method in your callback controller. This helped me find an error stemming from CSRF -- which I solved with help from this omniauth-facebook bug report https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/73

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make it work quickly with the Javascript SDK. Follow the example here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: My question is how to integrate these SDK components with Devise and OmniAuth.

Comment: Once the JavaScript has the token, then AJAX it up to the server running the OmniAuth/Devise code.

Comment: Conceptually this is what I figured. Just wondering if I can use any existing Devise controllers or if I have to rewrite the logic.